# How to ignore whole xml content based on filters on repeating child segments

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0, predicate

I need to ignore the whole XML content when there is a Group_2 segment with MATERIALSTATUS = Z7 and SALESORG = 1207 in a single ROW tag.

My Input xml is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULTS>
   <Groups>
      <Group_1>
         <RESULTSET_1>
            <ROW>
               <MATERIAL>12345</MATERIAL>
               <HARMCODE>3304.91.0000</HARMCODE>
               <ARTICLETYPE>005</ARTICLETYPE>
               <ARTICLESUBTYPE>014</ARTICLESUBTYPE>
               <MATCATGROUP/>
               <AUGROCERYPRODUCT/>
            </ROW>
         </RESULTSET_1>
      </Group_1>
      <Group_2>
         <RESULTSET_1>
            <ROW>
               <MATERIAL>12345</MATERIAL>
               <SALESORG>1119</SALESORG>
               <MATERIALSTATUS>Z7</MATERIALSTATUS>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
               <MATERIAL>12345</MATERIAL>
               <SALESORG>1207</SALESORG>
               <MATERIALSTATUS>D4</MATERIALSTATUS>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
               <MATERIAL>12345</MATERIAL>
               <SALESORG>1207</SALESORG>
               <MATERIALSTATUS>Z7</MATERIALSTATUS>
            </ROW>
         </RESULTSET_1>
      </Group_2>
   </Groups>
</RESULTS>
```

As this xml contains a Group_2 segment with MATERIALSTATUS = Z7 and SALESORG = 1207 in a single (third) ROW tag, my desired output should be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESULTS>
   <Groups/>
</RESULTS>
```

My XSLT code below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <RESULTS>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/RESULTS/Groups/*" group-by="*/ROW/MATERIAL">
                <Groups>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="(../Group_2/RESULTSET_1/ROW[MATERIALSTATUS = 'Z7'])">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="(../Group_2/RESULTSET_1/ROW[SALESORG = '1207'])">
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Groups>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </RESULTS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSL works for the given XML input. But when i have the SALESORG as 1207 (in one ROW segment) and MATERIALSTATUS as Z7 (in another ROW segment), I do not want the output to be suppressed. But my XSL suppress the whole xml by looking for 1207 in all of the 3  tags.

Please help me understand what can i do to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just check if the `current-group()` contains such a `ROW` and then not copy anything:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <RESULTS>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/RESULTS/Groups/*" group-by="*/ROW/MATERIAL">
            <Groups>
                <xsl:copy-of
                  select="if (current-group()[self::Group_2/RESULTSET_1/ROW[MATERIALSTATUS = 'Z7' and SALESORG = 1207]])
                          then () else current-group()"/>
            </Groups>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </RESULTS>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwF

One could also write that as

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <RESULTS>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/RESULTS/Groups/*" group-by="*/ROW/MATERIAL">
            <Groups>
                <xsl:copy-of
                  select="current-group()[not(some $row in current-group()[self::Group_2]/RESULTSET_1/ROW satisfies $row/MATERIALSTATUS = 'Z7' and $row/SALESORG = 1207)]"/>
            </Groups>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </RESULTS>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwF/1 or use a similar `xsl:choose` of course.